# x64-Assembly: Allocation of parameters in Stack although storing in registers

Tags: c++, c, assembly, 64-bit

I'm currently reading a very informative and good-to-follow book about C-Security and currently there is a chapter about Assembly. 
Considering the following C-Code:

```
1 void funktion (int a, int b, int c)
2 {
3         int  buff1[5];
4         char buff2[10];
5         buff1[0] = '6';
6         buff2[0] = 'A';
7         buff2[1] = 'B';
8 }
9 
10 int main (void)
11 {
12     int  i = 1;         
13     funktion (1, 2, 3);  
14     return 0;
15 }
```

When I debug the executable in `gdb` and `disassemble main`, I get the following output:

```
 # -----------FUNC_PROLOG----------
 24 0x00000000004004d4 <+0>:        push   %rbp
 28 0x00000000004004d5 <+1>:        mov    %rsp,%rbp 
 33 0x00000000004004d8 <+4>:        sub    $0x10,%rsp
 34 
 #----------FUNC_OPERATIONS----------
 39 0x00000000004004dc <+8>:        movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
 43 0x00000000004004e3 <+15>:       mov    $0x3,%edx
 44 0x00000000004004e8 <+20>:       mov    $0x2,%esi
 45 0x00000000004004ed <+25>:       mov    $0x1,%edi
```

The book I'm reading is from 2003, so I know that my compilation doesn't look exactly the same as like in the book, so I interpret this instruction (line 33) as the enlargement of the current stack-frame. In the book, there's a decrementation (= enlargement of the stack-frame) by 4 bytes, and I have a dec by 16 bytes: I think this is an optimation they made, so that the size of local var's (`int i` = 4 bytes) + the size of the parameters (`int a, int b, int c` = 12 bytes) = **16** bytes are allocated directly at the stack, and not pushing the stack each time, which is less efficient. However this could be a misinterpretation of mine which is relevant for the real question I have:

From line 43-45 the parameters are stored in reversed order, *but they are stored in registers*, **not** at the stack, how you can see there.

*So why is there memory allocated for the parameters at the stack, although they are not stored at the stack?*

Btw-Questions:

- At line 28 you can see a `mov` instruction. Why? I thought `AT&T` needs a size-suffix.
- Is it possible to adjust gdb so, that I see *direct values* in decimal, not in hexadecimal base?

Comment: Is the documentation you are reading for 32-bit or 64-bit code? In 64-bit code (which you have shown) not all parameters are passed on the stack (if they can be they'll be passed in registers). There is also a scratch area to save registers that will appear. If you are interested in the 64-bit ABI that defines the calling specification you might want to look at the [64bit System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) used by Linux (64-bit Windows uses a slightly different convention).

Comment: AT&T syntax doesn't require the size specifier if it can be inferred from the operands without ambiguity. With `movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)` you need a specifier because we don't know the size of data at `-0x4(%rbp)` so we must explicitly say the size for `movl`. In the case of `mov    $0x3,%edx` doesn't need it because `%edx` is a known size (32 bit register).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @MichaelPetch.
So that 16 bytes are that "Scratch-Area" (Shadow-Space, Home-Space).
Write an answer with that content, and I mark it as solution -_-.